# Replacing a value in XML file via bash

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file that I am trying edit via xmlstarlet in a bash script but I am unable to find any examples that have an xml formatted the same way as this one.  Below is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="StringCollections" type="ALINetCoreConsole.Config.StringCollections, ALINetCoreConsole"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="TCPAddress" value="192.168.xx.xx"/>
    <add key="TCPPort" value="2101" />
    <add key="ParsingFilesDirectory" value="/app/aliparsing"/>
    <add key="MessageBossAddress" value="messageboss:9092"/>
    <add key="AliRulesetReloadMinutes" value="30"/>
    <add key="PsapId" value=""/>
    <add key="MessageStarter" value="2"/>
    <add key="MessageEnder" value="3"/>
    <!-- Possible values are: Warn, Info, Debug -->
    <add key="LogLevel" value="Warn"/>
  </appSettings>

  <StringCollections>
    <HeartbeatValues>
      <add message="K"/>
      <add message="H"/>
    </HeartbeatValues>
  </StringCollections>
</configuration>
```

The specific value I am trying to change via xmlstarlet is **value="192.168.xx.xx"**

So far I have figured out how to delete the entire line but something isn't clicking with me on the correct syntax to just change the IP address in the Value field.

I currently have the script written to use sed to find and replace the IP but it's ugly and relies on cut/rev so if for some reason that particular line had an extra space at the end or something similar then it would fail.  I am looking for a more elegant and reliable solution with xmlstarlet.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's best to include the work you've done so we can help you. Normally, SO isn't a code writing service - more of a help-get-me-unstuck place.

Comment: I apologize.  There was a lot of things I had tried and the one thing I had working, sed, is pretty ugly.  I am more looking for the syntax required to do what I want but I don't know how to ask for that without kinda getting the code written for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update an attribute with xmlstartlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '//add[@value="192.168.xx.xx"]/@value' --value '1.2.3.4' file.xml
```

or

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '//add[@key="TCPAddress"]/@value' --value '1.2.3.4' file.xml
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Thank you so much.  I understand the syntax to address any of the other values.